# Strategy to continuously log an android and iOS mobile app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I utilize Ionic, which uses Cordova underneath. I have a separate service that can accept a `POST`.

Is there a better (more efficient/reliable/cleaner/etc.) way to continuously log the application via a debug mode besides copying the logs and sending them via `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to import your app project folder into the intel xdk, use their debug mode to run the app on a device, or use their wireless debug route. They generate a  tag with a url and you can wirelessly debug your app as it runs on your phone. Grab the intel xdk here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk#download . Then open it, on the bottom left you should see import a project, import your project, then click the debug tab on the top, follow the steps to get on device debuging. Profit.